# Can Markov State Models based on short-term non-equilibrium datasets also capture the dynamics towards equilibrium?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, markovianity

I am non-specialist who is new to the field of computational physics/biology. I have a few questions about the relevance and effectiveness of Markov State Models (MSM) in capturing the dynamics towards equilibrium.

It is my understanding that based upon recordings of the trajectories of some observed value of a system, it may be possible to fit a markov state model to it by discretising the trajectories into states and then estimating the transition matrix. However, these recorded trajectories are not necessarily of the equilibrium configuration, rather in my case consist of some transient change in the parameter followed by equilibration towards a time-independent mean value. If a markov state model is constructed from such data, will it also to some extend capture these relaxation characteristics?

An example of such a recorded trajectory is shown below:
[image]

As you can see, the trajectory consists of some initial transient phenomena that slowly converges onto a mean. Furthermore, the step like changes at fixed time-interval suggests a MSM might be reasonable.  I would like the Markov state model to capture the characteristics of this transient phenomena. By this I mean, if the MSM is simulated with similar initial conditions to the data then the relaxation behaviour (eg time-scales) should be similar.

Comment: +10. Welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future!! Have you figured out an answer to your question now during these 7 months? Please update us!

Comment: If the question is still of interest and you have any updates, let us know. We periodically go through unanswered questions to see if we can resolve them, but if they aren't of interest to the user any more, we tend to close them so we can manage the unanswered questions that are still actively seeking answers.

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.